# Oracle: Get schemes containing x using native dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql

There is an Oracle DB Server which contains a lot of schemes.

Some of them contain a table "CONTROLLERS" with a column "IPADDRESS".

I'm accessing the **dba_tab_cols** table, which also holds an "OWNER" column. Apparently, "OWNER" might be a keyword. That could be causing trouble.

However, when I run

```
SELECT owner from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'IPADDRESS' and table_name = 'CONTROLLERS';
```

**I am getting the desired output with the schema names.** But trying to put it to work within some dynamic SQL inside a loop didn't yield the results that I was hoping for.

```
DECLARE
ownername varchar(100);
BEGIN
FOR schema_rec IN (
        SELECT 'owner' into ownername from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'IPADDRESS' and table_name = 'CONTROLLERS')
LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ownername');
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NAME, IPADDRESS from ' || ownername || '.CONTROLLERS where IPADDRESS=''X.X.X.X'';';
END LOOP;
END;
```

It gives me this error message: *"invalid table name" on line 8* and I can't figure out what I did wrong. Hopefully, it's just some simple syntax issue.

I tried various stuff already. Putting the owner in single and double quotes and accessing the loop variable instead of "ownername" among others.

EDIT: This is what I got after fiddling around for a bit:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
ownername varchar(100);
BEGIN
FOR schema_rec IN (
        SELECT owner into ownername from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'IPADDRESS' and table_name = 'CONTROLLERS')
LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * from ' || schema_rec.owner || '.CONTROLLERS where IPADDRESS like ''1%''';
END LOOP;
END;
```

It doesn't output any errors anymore but doesn't output the desired list either.

Im not new to SQL but to Oracle and appreciate any suggestions/help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. Problem was that `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` requires the query to return a single row.

I got around that by using as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
ownername varchar(100);
ipcounter number;
ipaddress varchar(20):='X.X.X.X';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(ipaddress);
FOR schema_rec IN (
        SELECT owner into ownername from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'IPADDRESS' and table_name = 'CONTROLLERS')
LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT COUNT(*) from ' || schema_rec.owner || '.CONTROLLERS where IPADDRESS like ''X.X.X.X''') into ipcounter;
        IF ipcounter > 0 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Schema '||schema_rec.owner ||': Table "CONTROLLERS" contains IP '||ipcounter||' times.');
        END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```